# How to find index in ArrayList<Class> (Android)

Tags: android, arraylist, indexing, find

I use eclipse android

I need to index or object find in ArrayList

```
public class myclass
{
    int id;
    int count;
    String value;
}

mainactivity
{
    ArrayList<myclass> list = new ArrayList<myclass>();
    myclass mc = new myclass();
    mc.id=1;
    mc.count=20;
    mc.value="my value 1"
    list.add(mc);
    //add 100 record in list

    //how can i this
    int index = list.find(value="search value");
    //or this
    myclass founded = list.find(value="search value");
    //or this
    myclass founded2 = list.where(a => a.value="search value").first; //yes this is linq and lambda, but i cant linq in android
}
```

if I use for loop, I can find index but maybe arraylist has 1billion over record and I search 1000 values in arraylist

I dont want to use 1000 times for-loop in arraylist.
how can I this basicly

Comment: its even better to use a database and query the correct record whenever you need! why go for expensive arraylist and hashmaps

Answer (score 1):

You can use `indexOf()`

```
int index = list.indexOf(object)
```

Comment: but, object is class and I know just one variable's value in class. Ex: class: id=100, count=20, value="blue rock"; I search value="blue rock" in arraylist

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to find 1000 values inside your 1billion `ArrayList` record it is better not to use `ArrayList` here.
More preferable way for doing that is using `HashMap<String, YourClass>`.
Where first parameter is your id and second is element of your class.
You can easily found then element of your class by id. Approximately [O(1)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

If it is no matter how your values will be stored in `ArrayList` you can implements comparable interface in your class and support your collection in sorted way. So if your collection is sorted you can find your element with [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).
You should use this version of binary search

```
Collections.binarySearch(List<? extends T> list, T object, Comparator<? super T> comparator)
```

So you can implement you custom compator to check if your object is equal to something that you are finding.